# django on jython(cannot import name BaseDatabaseWrapper)

Tags: django, database, jython

I have a problem **buliding django on  jython**

I have already installed **django-jython , jython , django**

in **settings.py**  dababase engine I write :  **doj.db.backends.sqlite**

raiseImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:

**'doj.db.backends.sqlite' isn't an
available database backend.**
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'base', u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'

**Error was: cannot import name BaseDatabaseWrapper**

it seems that in **doj.db**  there is no these classes which I can find in **django.db**

and **I find in** site-packages\django_jython-1.7.0b2-py2.7.egg\doj\db\backends\sqlite\base.py

**there are :**

from doj.db.backends import JDBCBaseDatabaseWrapper as BaseDatabaseWrapper

from doj.db.backends import JDBCBaseDatabaseFeatures as BaseDatabaseFeatures

from doj.db.backends import JDBCBaseDatabaseOperations as BaseDatabaseOperations

from doj.db.backends import JDBCCursorWrapper as CursorWrapper

from doj.db.backends import JDBCConnection

**maybe the problem lies here**

**thanks for your help**

Comment: I was trying to get django_pyodbc to work as a backend, and solved it by downgrading django to 1.6. Maybe that will help.

Comment: thank you . although I gave up jython a month ago .

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. It's Django compatibility issue indeed. django-jython 1.7 works with Django 1.7.x (see https://pythonhosted.org/django-jython/release-notes.html#b2)